# Get screen dimensions inside page adapter?

Tags: java, android, screen

I'm trying to get screen dimensions inside page adapter. I could get it inside `MainActivity` and pass it to the adapter but it would be better to get it there. How can I do it, either directly inside the adapter or inside `instantiateItem`?

This is my code:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); // The method getWindowManager() is undefined for the type MyPagerAdapter
    display.getSize(size);
    ...
    }
```

Comment: try something like that <your file class name>.this.<methods> for example `MyActivity.this.getContextBlaBla()`  and then you can try Metrics or other stuff

Comment: I just tried that, I get: The method getContext() is undefined for the type MyPagerAdapter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From any context reference (such as in your `intantiateItem`), you can get a reference to the `DisplayMetrics` class by doing

`context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`

Which gives you a reference to the `DisplayMetrics` class [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

Particularly of use to you will be the `widthPixels` and `heightPixels` attributes of this, which return the raw pixel height and width for the device.

Answer (score 15):

You're almost there. You already have a [`context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). With that you can retrieve a `WindowManager` via [`getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29)

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: I tried `Context context = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)` but I get WINDOW_SERVICE cannot be resolved as a variable. It would great if I could get it outside the intatiateItem, so I can do it just one time.

Comment: I get `context cannot be resolved` I don't think I have a context, I'm trying to figure out how to get it

Comment: @Liso22 You had a context in your first version in `intantiateItem()` from `container.getContext()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int pxWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    float dpWidth = pxWidth / displayMetrics.density;
    int pxHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    float dpHeight = pxHeight / displayMetrics.density;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Do this with WindowManager

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```